# MongoDB generating same ID between inserts

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nosql

I am using pymongo and I am trying to insert dicts into mongodb database. My dictionaries look like this

```
{
    "name" : "abc",
    "Jobs" : [
        {
            "position" : "Systems Engineer (Data Analyst)",
            "time" : [
                "October 2014",
                "May 2015"
            ],
            "is_current" : 1,
            "location" : "xyz",
            "organization" : "xyz"
        },
        {
            "position" : "Systems Engineer (MDM Support Lead)",
            "time" : [
                "January 2014",
                "October 2014"
            ],
            "is_current" : 1,
            "location" : "xxx",
            "organization" : "xxx"
        },
        {
            "position" : "Asst. Systems Engineer (ETL Support Executive)",
            "time" : [
                "May 2012",
                "December 2013"
            ],
            "is_current" : 1,
            "location" : "zzz",
            "organization" : "xzx"
        },
    ],
    "location" : "Buffalo, New York",
    "education" : [
        {
            "school" : "State University of New York at Buffalo - School of Management",
            "major" : "Management Information Systems, General",
            "degree" : "Master of Science (MS), "
        },
        {
            "school" : "Rajiv Gandhi Prodyogiki Vishwavidyalaya",
            "major" : "Electrical and Electronics Engineering",
            "degree" : "Bachelor of Engineering (B.E.), "
        }
    ],
    "id" : "abc123",
    "profile_link" : "example.com",
    "html_source" : "<html> some_source_code </html>"
}
```

I am getting this error:

> pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index:
>   Linkedin_DB.employee_info.$*id* dup key: { :
>   ObjectId('56b64f6071c54604f02510a8') }

When I run my program 1st document gets inserted properly but when I insert the second document I get this error. When I start my script again the document which was not inserted because of this error get inserted properly and error comes for next document and this continues.

Clearly mognodb is using the same objecID during two inserts. I don't understand why mongodb is failing to generate a unique ID for new documents.

My code to save passed data:

```
class Mongosave:
    """
        Pass collection_name and dict data
        This module stores the passed dict in collection
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
        self.db = self.connection['Linkedin_DB']

    def _exists(self, id):
        #To check if user alredy exists
        return True if list(self.collection.find({'id': id})) else False

    def save(self, collection_name, data):
        self.collection = self.db[collection_name]
        if not self._exists(data['id']):
            print (data['id'])
            self.collection.insert(data)
        else:
            self.collection.update({'id':data['id']}, {"$set": data})
```

I can figure out why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't replicate this, can you show us how you are iterating through your dictionaries?

Comment: @SteveRossiter I am generating these dicts by crawling a website. Also, I am generating a similar dict and doing one insert at a time. in `save` data contains the dict data.

Comment: you're setting an "id" key, check out the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your save method is using a field called "id" to decide if it should do an insert or an upsert. You want to use "_id" instead. [You can read about the _id field and index here.](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-single/#index-type-id) PyMongo automatically adds an _id to you document if one is not already present. [You can read more about that here.](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#why-does-pymongo-add-an-id-field-to-all-of-my-documents)

Answer (score 1):

You might have inserted two copies of the same document into your collection in one run.

I cannot quite understand what do you mean by:

> When I start my script again the document which was not inserted because of this error get inserted properly and error comes for next document and this continues.

What I do know is if you do:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client['someDB']
collection = db['someCollection']
someDocument = {'x': 1}
for i in range(10):
    collection.insert_one(someDocument)
```

You'll get a:

> pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index:

This make me think although pymongo would generate a unique _id for you if you don't provide one, it is not guaranteed to be unique, especially if the document provided is not unique. Presumably pymongo is using some sort of hash algorithm on what you insert for their auto-gen _id without changing the seed.

Try generate your own _id and see if it would happen again.

Edit:
I just tried this and it works:

```
for i in range(10):
    collection.insert_one({'x':1})
```

This make me think the way pymongo generates _id is associated with the object you feed into it, this time I'm not referencing to the same object anymore and the problem disappeared.

Are you giving your database two references of a same object?